# 1.) Do all sidechains require their own token, consensus, node operators, etc?

Tags: sidechains

I just finished IOHK’s whiteboard video about sidechains.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04D2BP33YI8

I felt like I absorbed much of the information like NiPoPow’s and the problems that sidechains can solve. However, I am left with a few burning questions:

1.) Do all sidechains require their own token, consensus, node operators, etc?
2.) How does the receiving chain mint the newly transferred coin? How is this even possible? I thought minting was only allowed based on a monetary policy. Is this a special exemption? I understand chain a will burn the token, and chain b will validate bc of the NiPoPow, but I don’t understand how chain b can mint a new token on request.

Answer (score 2):

Sidechains do require their own tokens, consensus protocols, and operators, but there's no reason why all three of those *have* to be different than the tokens, protocols, and operators of the main chain.

They *can* be different, which is why sidechains are so flexible and versatile, it really just depends on the needs/purposes of the specific sidechain.

For example, a sidechain (or Hydra Head) whose sole purpose is to scale ADA or native token transactions can use sidechain-ADA on a 1:1 basis to mainchain-ADA, a modified version of Ouroboros that prioritizes speed over security, and a node operator that has already built a solid track record of distributed systems administration (i.e. established SPO's).

On the other hand, a side chain can have its own monetary policy with a (locally) global accounting style and arbitrary tokenomics, or any combination of services.

Sky's the limit!